# How to have pages being inside other pages in the URL?

Tags: html, css, url, slash

This might be a dumb question, but I can't find the name of what I'm looking for.
I'm creating my portfolio and I would like to have "sub-pages", currently I'm just using href to link to pages, but i would love to have all my pieces inside a "work" page.

For example, medirect is inside work and work being inside the index.

[www.basedesign.com/work/medirect](http://www.basedesign.com/work/medirect)

All the help is appreciated. I'm using HTML+CSS, and I have a .htaccess to remove the html from URL

I don't know what to look for this component

Comment: If you are just using plain html files, then you can create such a url structure by having a /work/ folder inside the main directory and have the medirect.html file inside of the work folder.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know what you mean but you aren't looking for [iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe?retiredLocale=de) right?

Comment: Sounds more like they are just looking for folders actually.

Comment: Soi, i have an "index" page with a link to a "work" page, then i have many projects as their own page. right now it looks like  this
index.com/projectname

i would love to have something like this
index.com/work/projectname

Comment: Go to your root directory (where you currently have your projectname.html) and create a new folder called "work". Then move your projectname.html into your new work folder. Now your link will look like "https://example.com/work/projectname".